# I have a .adf file and want to select an elevation range

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, elevation, topography, bathymetry

I'm super new to GIS.

I downloaded a USGS 30m resolution map of a bay, and now I want to specify all areas that are between 0m and -30m elevation. I need to find where a defined area contains 0 and -30m elevation.

The file is .adf, do I need to convert it to a .shp? I went into symbology and added all values, so I can see the sections that are between 0 and -30m, but I don't know how to select them and do anything with them.

I have ArcMap 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Comment: There is no such format as `.adf`, though a great many different formats may have `.adf` extensions, depending on the parent directory, parent's sibling directories, and sibling files.  If you **edit** the question to specify what link you used and what exact files you downloaded, we can probably point you in the direction of what you *should have* downloaded.

Comment: Check out this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27420/exporting-selected-raster-graphics-using-arcgis-desktop

Comment: As typed and edited I'm still not sure what your goal is but the linked Q:A (*Exporting Selected Raster Graphics using ArcGIS Desktop?*) seems very likely to get you what you need.